# Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6.1

I'm working in a WinForm app in 4 layers:

1. DAL (Data access)
2. BOL (Bussiness objects)
3. BAL (Bussiness access)
4. INT (Intermediate access).

I'm using the Intermediate layer to run any operation needed by the Presentation layer, trying to make it independent, as we can use it in a WinForm, ASP, and so.

I've created a Class that executes those operations like this:

```
// Clase: ProjectStatusMID
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Trevo.FrameWork
{
   public class ProjectStatusMID
   {
      #region Propiedades

      private ProjectStatusBOL _Data = new ProjectStatusBOL();
      private ProjectStatusBAL _Operations = new ProjectStatusBAL();

      private Acciones _Action = Acciones.Nada;

      #endregion Propiedades

      public ProjectStatusBOL Data
      {
         get { return _Data; }
         set
         {
            _Data = value;
         }
      }

      public ProjectStatusBAL Operations
      {
         get { return _Operations; }
         set
         {
            _Operations = value;
         }
      }

      public Acciones Action
      {
         get { return _Action; }
         set
         {
            _Action = value;
         }
      }

      public int IDProject
      {
         get { return _Data.IDProject; }
         set
         {
            _Data.IDProject = value;
         }
      }

      public List<Codigos> ProjectsList
      {
         get { return LoadProjects(); }
      }

      public ProjectStatusMID()
      {
         //Load();
      }

      public void Load()
      {
         Operations.Consultar(Data);
      }

      public List<Codigos> LoadProjects()
      {
         List<Codigos> oRet = new List<Codigos>();

         MyProjectsBAL _Operations = new MyProjectsBAL();
         MyProjectsBOL _Data = new MyProjectsBOL();

         List<MyProjectsBOL> _MyList = _Operations.Lista(_Data);

         foreach (MyProjectsBOL o in _MyList)
         {
            oRet.Add(new Codigos(o.IDProject, o.Project));
         }

         return oRet;
      }

   }
}
// Clase: ProjectStatusMID
```

At the front-end (in this case is WinForm), we are instancing this class as follows:

```
 ProjectStatusMID OO = new ProjectStatusMID();
```

So, the issue comes when calling one of the methods:

```
     parProject.DataSource = OO.LoadProjects();
```

Everything is referenced, the app compiles without any problems, the project that contains the class is part of the solution in a separated project (as any other layer), BUT we have the following error:

*System.MissingMethodException occurred
  HResult=-2146233069
  Message=Método no encontrado: 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 Trevo.FrameWork.ProjectStatusMID.LoadProjects()'.
  Source=WorkLoadPresentation
  StackTrace:
       en Trevo.FrameWork.PS_ProjectStatus_Datos.CargarListas()
       en Trevo.FrameWork.PS_ProjectStatus_Datos.PS_ProjectStatus_Datos_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) en C:\Users\fbravo\OneDrive\Particular_Sistemas\WorkLoad\WorkLoadPresentation\ProjectStatus\PS_ProjectStatus_Datos.cs:línea 25
  InnerException:*

I've tried to make the class static, re-creating the entire app, deleting the GAC, and so, but a week loose trying different things.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be several issues.  The most common one is that you included the DLL library which is the wrong version (e.g. without the method that's missing).  Easiest thing to do is to open the exe in the decompiler (e.g. Reflector) and step through it.

Another issue could be the wrong bitness (but probably not).

Comment: Understood.The first one I'm almost sure is not. I've deleted any WorkLoadMID.dll (the name of the library) existing in our servers and terminals. After that, recompiled all and the problem is the same. I will check the bitness because is one thing I didn't try. Thanks @AngryHacker!

Comment: @Nane Definetely walk through your code with the decompiler.

Comment: Seems to. Is not my expertise area, but will try. Thanks again!

Comment: Was in that way. An old version of a DLL was being loaded. Thanks and sorry

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you referenced the external project dll in your main Winforms application

Comment: Thanks, but is not. It is referenced in those projects that uses it (only one, really). I've tested to reference it in the main project, but didn't work either. Thank you